# Sending messages of different types to Android Handler

Tags: android

Is there a way to distinguish between types of messages sent to an Android Handler? For example, I have 2 background threads and would like the handler to recognize which thread a message came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the public field 'what' ("User-defined message code so that the recipient can identify what this message is about.") is used for that

Answer (score 1):

I have never used messages in Android so far, but [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) suggests that you can add custom values to a message (which would make sense anyway `;)` ), so why don't you just let the thread write his `id` or whatever identifies him into the message before sending it?

And of course check for the `id` in the Handler.